# Convert row values to string

Tags: r

How can I convert row values that have multiple instances each, e.g. numbers 1-6 for each index value (‘double’ index), into a descriptive string value?

For example, all ‘1’s in the column should become ‘jumping’ and all ‘3’s should become ‘falling’.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that it the variable is really a nominal/categorical variable, which in r is called a factor?Could you please provide some sample data?  it will likely be a combination of the as.factor() and levels() functions.

Comment: Yes, the ‘number’ describes a factor in a category. Example: [activity] 1 1 1 1 5 5 5 4 4 4, this should then coerce to the ‘text’ values to form a new list with the actual activities. Thanks!

Comment: (*[activity] is a column, not a row)

Comment: Please update your question with the information rather than putting it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1:3),
  b = c(4:6),
  c = c(7:9)
)

#setting column a to be a factor
df$a <- as.factor(df$a)

#creating a vector of level names where positions correspond to 
#the numbers I want to replace
name_vec <- c("jumping", "running", "falling")

levels(df$a) <- name_vec
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out.